# R claims packages that doParallel depends on are not available even though they are installed and can be loaded

Tags: r, linux, foreach, dplyr, doparallel

I am trying to install the `doParallel` package on a shared cluster (Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) where I do not have root privileges.  The cluster is running R version 3.5.0 (I have asked if this can be updated).

I've pasted the output from `install.packages("doParallel",dependencies=T)` below. R claims that `dplyr` is required by `recipes` but could not be found.  But I've installed `dplyr` and can load it without any issues.  Another package that `doParallel` requires is `caret`, which in turn requires `recipes`.  The installation of `caret` fails because of the previous failure to install `recipes`.  R also claims that `foreach` required by `doParallel` but could not be found, even though I previously installed it and can load it.

I've tried installing these packages separately, but it leads down a rabbit hole of many other dependencies and R complaining that packages are not available.  I've tried many of the suggestions on SO for similar problems, including:

- deleting old R libraries and reinstalling packages
- manually installing dependent packages (placing the source files where R should be able to find them)
- shutting down all R processes and restarting
- many of the solution seems to involve issues with Windows installations and working with RStudio. These are not relevant since this is a linux machine and I am doing everything from the command line.

R gives the following warning message when trying to install `doParallel`:

> Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3

Perhaps that is the source of the problem. Unfortunately, I do not have control over R updates on the cluster.

Thanks for any suggestions about solutions.

UPDATE: the suggestion by @r2evans to install `dplyr` from source and then install `doParallel` worked.  I was able to install `doParallel` and its dependencies successfully and execute the R code.

Adding output requested by @r2evans (thanks for looking into this):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0
```

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/<path to personal library>" "/usr/lib64/R/library"               
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

```
> install.packages("doParallel",dependencies=T)
Installing package into ‘...’ <path omitted for security reasons>
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘recipes’, ‘caret’

trying URL 'https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/recipes_0.1.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 633375 bytes (618 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 618 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/caret_6.0-86.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 5264447 bytes (5.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/doParallel_1.0.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 173578 bytes (169 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 169 KB

* installing *source* package ‘recipes’ ...
** package ‘recipes’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘recipes’
    finding HTML links ... done
    add_step                                html  
    bake                                    html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    check_class                             html  
    check_cols                              html  
    check_missing                           html  
    check_name                              html  
    check_new_values                        html  
    check_range                             html  
    check_type                              html  
    detect_step                             html  
    discretize                              html  
    fixed                                   html  
    format_ch_vec                           html  
    formula.recipe                          html  
    fully_trained                           html  
    has_role                                html  
    juice                                   html  
    names0                                  html  
    prep                                    html  
    prepper                                 html  
    print.recipe                            html  
    rand_id                                 html  
    recipe                                  html  
    recipes-internal                        html  
    recipes                                 html  
    recipes_pkg_check                       html  
    reexports                               html  
    roles                                   html  
    selections                              html  
    step                                    html  
    step_BoxCox                             html  
    step_YeoJohnson                         html  
    step_arrange                            html  
    step_bagimpute                          html  
    step_bin2factor                         html  
    step_bs                                 html  
    step_center                             html  
    step_classdist                          html  
    step_corr                               html  
    step_count                              html  
    step_cut                                html  
    step_date                               html  
    step_depth                              html  
    step_discretize                         html  
    step_downsample                         html  
    step_dummy                              html  
    step_factor2string                      html  
    step_filter                             html  
    step_geodist                            html  
    step_holiday                            html  
    step_hyperbolic                         html  
    step_ica                                html  
    step_integer                            html  
    step_interact                           html  
    step_intercept                          html  
    step_inverse                            html  
    step_invlogit                           html  
    step_isomap                             html  
    step_knnimpute                          html  
    step_kpca                               html  
    step_kpca_poly                          html  
    step_kpca_rbf                           html  
    step_lag                                html  
    step_lincomb                            html  
    step_log                                html  
    step_logit                              html  
    step_lowerimpute                        html  
    step_meanimpute                         html  
    step_medianimpute                       html  
    step_modeimpute                         html  
    step_mutate                             html  
    step_mutate_at                          html  
    step_naomit                             html  
    step_nnmf                               html  
    step_normalize                          html  
    step_novel                              html  
    step_ns                                 html  
    step_num2factor                         html  
    step_nzv                                html  
    step_ordinalscore                       html  
    step_other                              html  
    step_pca                                html  
    step_pls                                html  
    step_poly                               html  
    step_profile                            html  
    step_range                              html  
    step_ratio                              html  
    step_regex                              html  
    step_relevel                            html  
    step_relu                               html  
    step_rename                             html  
    step_rename_at                          html  
    step_rm                                 html  
    step_rollimpute                         html  
    step_sample                             html  
    step_scale                              html  
    step_shuffle                            html  
    step_slice                              html  
    step_spatialsign                        html  
    step_sqrt                               html  
    step_string2factor                      html  
    step_unknown                            html  
    step_unorder                            html  
    step_upsample                           html  
    step_window                             html  
    step_zv                                 html  
    summary.recipe                          html  
    terms_select                            html  
    tidy.recipe                             html  
    tunable.step                            html  
    update.step                             html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : package ‘dplyr’ required by ‘recipes’ could not be found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/rigel/stats/users/gjw10/rpackages2/recipes’
* installing *source* package ‘doParallel’ ...
** package ‘doParallel’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘doParallel’
    finding HTML links ... done
    doParallel-package                      html  
    registerDoParallel                      html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : package ‘foreach’ required by ‘doParallel’ could not be found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘<path to personal library>/doParallel’
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘<path to personal library>/caret’

The downloaded source packages are in

    ‘/tmp/Rtmpyd0cpT/downloaded_packages’

Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("doParallel", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("doParallel", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘doParallel’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("doParallel", dependencies = T) :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by the warning followed by dplyr-not-found. Can you include the output from `sessionInfo()` (or `sessioninfo::session_info()`) and `.libPaths()`? (in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) this time, please, it makes it a lot easier to read)

Comment: `library` is known to issue warnings when in fact the action fails, which *might* (I'm not certain) be producing the warning with no apparent failure. Can you try to install `dplyr` *from source*? I know it takes a long time to compile, but it should past that warning and perhaps enable the rest.

Comment: The suggestion to install `dplyr` from source worked.  I've edited my post to indicate this. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Did it take 644 days to compile from source? Wow, sorry about that suggestion ... ;-) (To confirm, then ... this resolves the question completely? If not ... the R and `dplyr` versions are sufficiently old that it is likely a good idea to upgrade both before reattempting ...)

Comment: This did resolve the question completely.  I'll invoke the standard pandemic response that it seemed like I was working on this only a few days ago (not 644)!  I actually stopped using the cluster where the problem occurred because there were too many other headaches with it.  I bought a Mac Pro which turns out to be just as fast and much easier to work on.  I thought a much delayed response was better than none since others might run into this problem and need help.